# updating new version on play store that would cause previously installed apps to crash on update

Tags: java, android

I have an application(1.0) on store. I have used Couchbase in it to store data for offline use. Now, for v1.1 I have switched to SQLite and changed Data structure in some places, so on updating to 1.1 the app may crash or wont show any data because there will be no data in new database(SQLite).

To prevent above issue I have created a migration/setup-data method(only run one time after v1.1 update) which is downloading and dumping data in SQLite.

I want to know if there is any other technique or way to achieve backward compatibility ?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are hoping to achieve/avoid with your question.

Comment: @CoryCharlton I dont want to lose my current users....i am afraid the app would crash on update.

Comment: Understood. I assume you are already testing the upgrade process right? If not you should do so in order to find and correct any potential crashes. As far as handling a change like the one you are implementing it sounds like you are doing it correctly in detecting the update and initializing the new database correctly.

Comment: @CoryCharlton yes I am testing the update process. I just want to make sure that I am doing this the right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done by subclassing SQLiteOpenHelper to manage your database.  It sounds like you're creating the DB for the first time, so you could just import the data in the onCreate() method after you set up your schema.

SQLiteOpenHelper takes care of tracking the version of the database and only running the onCreate/onUpgrade methods when needed.